# Capture all audio on a PC and stream it to another?

Tags: c#, audio, streaming

Imagine this scenario: You have a desktop and a laptop. The desktop has a high end set of speakers, the laptop does not. You currently use Synergy to share your mouse and keyboard, but audio is a problem.

Is there a way in C# to create a client that captures all of the sound on a PC(I'm thinking like a virtual sound card) and streams it to server that hosts the real sound card?

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do some time ago - but had no time to dig any further. Looking forward to the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a programming solution - but airfoil with airfoil speakers will do what you want and it's not expensive.

http://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/speakers.php

Comment: If there is a solution out there, why reinvent the wheel. Thanks for the link; in all my googling for an answer to this I never came across this software. It doesn't look like creating a virtual driver in c# is feasible anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Streaming sound shouldn't be a problem if you design something like a ring buffer in case you have lags in the network to avoid breaking the sound wave.

For capture though, I don't see any easy solution short of creating a virtual WDM driver that you put on top of the sound card (either input or output) you want to capture.

Comment: I'm confident that streaming won't be an issue, it's creating the virtual sound card that has me stumped. I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

There is AirFoil, as morechilli mentioned. It works with minimal setup, however the output is very noticeably latent.

The [PulseAudio](http://pulseaudio.org/) project might hold the key to low-latency. A lot of [relevant questions](https://superuser.com/search?q=pulseaudio+windows) on SuperUser.

Comment: It looks like AirFoil definitely does what I want it to do. IDK if its worth buying if there is a delay however.

Comment: There's a trial version that runs for 10 minutes before cutting to static.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the solution you're looking for, but I quite often shoutcast over my home network using winamp and the shoutcast server. If it's just music you want to listen to, this will do the trick. However (and I admit I have not tested this), you can tell the encoder what to listen to - normally you just get it to listen to the output buffer of winamp, but there is a setting that allows it to listen to the output to your soundcard.

http://www.shoutcast.com/download

Comment: I looked into this, but I'm looking to stream *everything* that gets sent to the sound card; sound from chrome, wmp, a game, w/e happens to be sending info to the sound card. It's looking like AirFoil is going to be my best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you write a driver that is a virtual sound card and IPC's off the information to a service that streams the data out.